# How to create a common source of data that all classes and widgets can use in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have multiple classes,widgets,listviews and pages that use the same data that is coming from cloud firestore. The problem is that every time I open a new page I have to fetch the same data that was in the previous page from cloud firestore and this will increase the reads of docs. So how can I create something that is a common source of data and also updates with the update of values in cloud firestore and not just normal pass of data between pages.

Maybe some solution using the new provider package can help but I am not sure or creating one global stream that all classes can listen to but what I am afraid of is that the reads with every connection to the stream will be counted or is it just the first initialization of the stream that counts the number of reads??

Comment: Well, it depends on the application type. If it requires live updates then you have to use firstore stream (that mean read on every page). But if you are accessing a specific date which is not going to change then you can store in an array and access it anywhere. I used the scope Model for this you can also do with the provider.

Comment: It depends on your code architecture. Try Redux

Comment: My data is always changing, it some kind of online game where any player at any instant can enter and change something

Comment: I use singleton classes sometimes whenever I have to centralize data for my apps. As far as for changing data you can try listening for real-time updates inside this singleton.

Comment: @AliHussam any code example or tut?

Comment: The BLoC pattern works well with Firestore streams. Try researching that.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is at risk of changing, then you definitely want to subscribe to the Stream using QuerySnapshot. If you use state management, you'll be able to pass the data to any widget that needs it. Avoid putting. your query in the widgets. Look into using BLoC ([popular implementation](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc)), [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) + ChangeNotifiers or Streams, or other solutions for state management. There are some others, but these are popular **complete** options. Provider by itself does not solve this problem. It can provide a piece to the puzzle though. You really need to understand state management at this point in your game. It's required to go forward and save you reads and writes.

Answer (score 1):

My App also works with The Cloud Firestore and I use BLoC to fetch the data from the Firestore. I call my BLoC class in the main when the App starts. 
If you don't have too many widgets, you can pass the data to your widget. If you have a lot of widget, you could use Inherited widgets to make the data available for all the widgets in your App.

Two interesting videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fahC3ky_zW0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbm3hjPjQMk

Comment: If I create a global stream to a collection in cloudfirestore and connect multiple widgets to it will this result in multiple reads or just the reads generated by the global stream?

Comment: If you use BLoC and read the Data in the main, the other widgets will not read the data from the Firestore again. You just have to pass your BLoC to the other Widgets. Your App will only read the data when it starts and when there is a change in the Firestore.